# Unknown error has occurred. The form template has been published to the server but it can only be opened in InfoPath Filler

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, infopath, external-content-type, external-list

I have gotten this error before and to fix it, I created a new external list and new form. But when going back in and editing the new form, it doesn't even publish and keeps giving me this error. I tried creating a new external list and form again, but it still keeps giving me the same error. I also tried the recommended sharepoint solution to add the Desktop feature, but my computer already has it installed. I am not locked out of my account either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you edit the new form?

I can publish the form successfully via SharePoint Designer->Edit external list->Design Forms in InfoPath under Actions tab->Item.

Reference: [How to: Customize External List Forms Using Microsoft InfoPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee554886(v%3Doffice.14))